# ComboBox : retrieving value of the selected Item

Tags: gwt

I am using ComboBox for Dropdown. and when I am select the item,it doesnot pick the value of it.
Code for comboBox :

```
final SimpleComboBox<String> combo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
        combo.setForceSelection(true);
        combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
        combo.setFieldLabel("Calculation MethodNames");
        combo.add(cList);
        formPanel.add(combo);
```

I am retrieving the value as below:

```
fundSalesCreditCalcMethodDTO.setCalculationMethodName(calculationMethodName.getValue(calculationMethodName.getSelectedIndex()));
```

Can somebody please help

Comment: Your box is called `combo`, not `calculationMethodName`.

Comment: Which widget library is this coming from? There's no `ComboBox` in GWT proper. Please add appropriate tag.